# Silverlight : MouseLeftButtonUp is not triggered

Tags: silverlight, drawing, mouseleftbuttonup

I'm new to Silverlight and I'm working on drawing a rectangle on the screen in the run time,

I have a class ( SelectionBox ), and on the main page, I have a canvas,
when clicking on that Canvas I have the following function called

```
private void BeginDrawing(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _initXPos = e.GetPosition(drawingArea).X;
            _initYPos = e.GetPosition(drawingArea).Y;
            _selectionBox = new SelectionBox ();
            drawingArea.Children.Add(_selectionBox);
            _isDrawing = true;
        }
```

and that Handler has been added through blend Events (MouseLeftButtonDown)

when the mouse is moving, the following method is called, also added through Blend events,

```
private void UpdateSelectionBox(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(!_isDrawing &&)
                return;
            double rectWidth, rectHeight, rectXPos, rectYPos;
            if (e.GetPosition(drawingArea).X >= _initXPos)
            {
                rectWidth = e.GetPosition(drawingArea).X - _initXPos;
                rectXPos = _initXPos;
            }
            else
            {
                rectWidth = _initXPos - e.GetPosition(drawingArea).X;
                rectXPos = e.GetPosition(drawingArea).X;
            }

            if (e.GetPosition(drawingArea).Y >= _initYPos)
            {
                rectHeight = e.GetPosition(drawingArea).Y - _initYPos;
                rectYPos = _initYPos;
            }
            else
            {
                rectHeight = _initYPos - e.GetPosition(drawingArea).Y;
                rectYPos = e.GetPosition(drawingArea).Y;
            }

            _selectionBox.Width = Math.Abs(rectWidth - 20);
            _selectionBox.Height = Math.Abs(rectHeight - 20);
            Canvas.SetLeft(_selectionBox, Math.Abs(rectXPos - 20));
            Canvas.SetTop(_selectionBox, Math.Abs(rectYPos - 20));
        }
```

when the mouseLeftButtonUp is triggered, the following Handler should work,

```
private void StopDrawingAndSelect(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _isDrawing = false;
            drawingArea.Children.Remove(_selectionBox);
        }
```

but unfortunately it never triggers, I put a break point and try to debug it but it never reaches,, I'm not sure Why, this is the XAML for the SelectionBox class

```
<UserControl
    ...

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Rectangle Fill="#00F4F4F5" Stroke="Black" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And this is the XAML of the MainPage

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SelectionBoxTraining"
    x:Class="SelectionBoxTraining.MainPage"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Canvas Margin="165,0,0,0" x:Name="drawingArea" MouseLeftButtonDown="BeginDrawing" Background="#FF959FD6" MouseMove="UpdateSelectionBox" MouseLeftButtonUp="StopDrawingAndSelect" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Please can anybody help me? I tried a lot of things to do but that didn't work

I hope I find help here,

NOTE: The  properties are not included in the XAML code upthere to save space,

Thank You.

Comment: Oh,, I forgot to say that If I Apply the StopDrawingAndSelect to the RightMouseButtonUp it works

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the reason is that your rectangle is getting the UP event and (somehow?) not bubbling it up to the canvas. So try to set ishitestvisible to false:

```
private void BeginDrawing(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _initXPos = e.GetPosition(drawingArea).X;
            _initYPos = e.GetPosition(drawingArea).Y;
            _selectionBox = new SelectionBox ();

            _selectionBox.IsHitTestVisible = false;

            drawingArea.Children.Add(_selectionBox);
            _isDrawing = true;
        }
```

`

Comment: I Tried that, and Unfortunately it didn't work .. !!

Thank You very much for trying to help :)

Comment: Could you create(reproduce i problem into) a sample project and attach it to this thread?

Answer (score 0):

It's now working, even though I'm not convinced of the answer,
but I changed the OnMouseUp Function by double-click on Blend's events place for MouseUp, and it became

```
private void drawingArea_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _isDrawing = false;
            drawingArea.Children.Remove(_selectionBox);
        }
```

does anyone has an explanation for what caused the problem? does the name of the handler has that effect? I Wonder..